# How Actually start(); works in Java Threading

Tags: java

Here is the Example Code:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run Entered");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread obj=new Thread(new HelloRunnable());
        obj.start();
        System.out.println("ABC");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
ABC
Run Entered
```

Why ABC before the `run()'s` code?

Even I create 3 threads. But still ABC print first;

```
obj.start();
obj1.start();
obj2.start();
```

Really I tried to search about this, but unable to find the query for this.

Comment: One line - In java thread execution is nondeterministic. And when you do `obj.start();` then essentially you are starting a new thread and its execution sequence is nondeterministic.

Comment: Likely the answer is simply that the thread that called `start` was already running while the thread that executes `run` needed some time to start up.

Comment: Lets first take a look at various states a thread can be in : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html. That said, call to 'start' does not run as in execute the thread at once. It puts thread in a `runnable` state meaning out of `n` threads in runnable state, schedular can pick any one and start executing thus putting it in `running` state. Thus calling `start` is just making the thread available for running or ready for running and at the mercy of schedular to make it run

Comment: @Satarangi_Re thanks for the link, let me read all.

Comment: @Satarangi_Re I already know this state. but don't know the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because the `HelloRunnable.run` method is executed in another thread than the one printing `ABC`. They execute concurrently, that's the point of threads. Therefore, any of the two may access a certain resource, like the stdout, before the other.

Comment: Sorry My english is week can you explain in easy way. As I understood your answer is that, there is no guarantee when thread execute.

Comment: What other language do you speak- ? :D I can speak french and spanish, but you should get used to english if you want to be a programmer (this will come naturally if you keep reading and writing on SO for example)

Comment: URDU :) Ritish's answer clearing my concepts and also creating more question about CPU mechanism on threads. Any how now going to google to get answer, because now I got queries to search.

Comment: The basic idea is that in a sequential program all instructions execute in a deterministic order whereas concurrent pograms have their their instructions executed in any possible order. If a particular order is required, you need to enforce it using synchronization. And sorry I don't speak urdu :D Good luck in your searches

Comment: this will be my last comment because I don't want to bother you more for my poor understanding..!! There is 2 thread..!! 1st main's thread that work is to create another thread `obj.start();` also `println("ABC");` first it will create the thread by `obj.start();` but that thread is in runnable stage in that moment main's thread will execute own other instructions then next one is `println("ABC");`, I'm right? YES or No? :P

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask (good) questions, that's a QA website after all. You seem to have understood this small code. After executing `start`, the main thread goes to the next instruction while a new thread kicks off. What happens next is undeterministic

Answer (score 0):

Would be reverse or like this. You started a "Thread". You are running on the main thread. So you have two independent running code. How do you guarantee that one will finish its work before the other ?

Try to sleep main thread after starting other threads. With

`Thread.sleep(2000);`

Then other threads would finish their works. You can see that ABC printed last.

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run Entered");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread obj=new Thread(new HelloRunnable());
        obj.start();
        try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        System.out.println("ABC");
    }

}
```

They are parallel works so you don't have a guarantee that ABC printed lastly or firstly. Depends on the machine CPU, works you have.

Comment: the method "main" is where you start running the code. This is main thread area, all process flow here. When you fork a thread they are different than main thread. Assume you have different processes but they are in the same executable process. They have different work/task. Some has heavy some has light.

Comment: how I can sleep main thread? So, I will be able to print ABC at the end.

Comment: this will be my last comment because I don't want to bother you more for my poor understanding..!! There is 2 thread..!! 1st main's thread that work is to create another thread `obj.start();` also `println("ABC");` first it will create the thread by `obj.start();` but that thread is in runnable stage in that moment main's thread will execute own other instructions then next one is `println("ABC");`, I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

When you call obj.start(), internally it spawns a new thread. So at that stage, you have 2 threads in your process, One is main thread, and one is new thread.

Each thread needs cpu to execute, and that's driven by cpu scheduling queue. If main thread hold the cpu, then out put will be what you saw. If context switch happens just after the statement obj.start();then cpu is given to new thread, Then you will see the thread output first and then the main output.

So the behavior is undeterministic as you can never predict that after which statement the context switch will happen.

Also what you see in the code is not what gets executed at the cpu. At the cpu assembly is executed. So even if you say that you were executing obj.start(), but you can never say on which assembly instruction you really were when context switch happened.

Comment: `main` thread is same as other threads ( Thread obj etc.. )? or it is just a task for CPU?

Comment: @NewBie cpu scheduling queue treat all the threads same. There are other methods to change the priority of threads, but that's different issue.